# identity involving gamma function

Tags: limits, gamma-function, dirac-delta

Is this identity
$$
\lim_{x\to0}[\Gamma(x+\imath b_1)+\Gamma(x-\imath b_2)]=2\pi\delta(b_1-b_2),\;\imath=\sqrt{-1}.
$$
supposed to be known? Any reference?